# pip install numpy (python 2.7) fails with errorcode 1

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I'm installing numpy through pip on python 2.7.9... I checked `pip list`, and it returns `pip (1.5.6), setuptools (12.0.4)`. I'm running on Windows 7 64-bit, and I've tried both Python 32 and 64-bit versions.

`pip install numpy` ends with:

```
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\jon\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_jon\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\jon\appdata\local\temp\pip-qnynnf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed 

--compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\jon\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_jon\numpyStoring 

debug log for failure in C:\Users\jon\pip\pip.log
```

When I checked stackoverflow for other posts about errorcode 1, their solutions were to make sure you have an up-to-date version of `setuptools`. I installed Python 2.7.9 from the main website, and it comes with both `setuptools` and `pip` ready to go. Plus I made sure my system had them installed by checking `pip list`.

So instead I looked up the debug log the console error told me to go to, at `C:\Users\jon\pip\pip.log`. It's quite lengthy, but near the end it says

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
```

I went to that url, downloaded the compiler, and ran `pip install numpy` again. It didn't throw errorcode 1 this time, but had a different issue. It printed a huge wall of text to the screen, which never happened the last time I installed numpy/matplotlib/etc. It printed the text for a few minutes, then froze and stopped.

I'm not sure how to proceed?

If it helps I can post the pip debug log.

Comment: there is meant to be a *huge wall of text* when it is compiling. What was the last thing it printed?

Comment: Installing numpy with pip will attempt to compile it.  This can be painful on Windows, esepcially 64-bit.  You are better off using an EXE installer from [this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's pretty indecipherable. Here's a screenshot I took: [http://i.imgur.com/aAvYAJ4.png]

Comment: try the gohlke prebuilt binary Brenbarn suggested and if you have no luck add any error output to your question

Comment: I'm also for the precompiled EXE installer.

Comment: Which wheel did you download?  Did you put it in the right directory?  In your screenshot it looks like you have two underscores in `win__amd64.whl`, but the file only has one(`win_amd64.whl`).

Comment: @BrenBarn Yeah, I put in the wrong file name (deleted my comment asking about it, but you got it anyway).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Download the wheel (.whl file) file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and install with pip:

1. `pip install wheel` to install support for wheel files.
2. `pip install numpy‑1.9.1+mkl‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl` to install the wheel.