# Installing ggplot for python failed with error code 1

Tags: python, ggplot2

I am trying to install ggplot for Python using

```
pip install ggplot
```

but I get an error message saying
[image]

I am using Python2.7 on Windows8. I looked at the suggestions and among other things tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142839/pip-install-numpy-python-2-7-fails-with-errorcode-1)

1. pip install wheel to install support for wheel files.
2. pip install ggplot-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl to install the wheel. I downloaded the whl file from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ggplot).

Upon doing this I got further messages saying:
Failed building wheel for scipy
Failed cleaning build for scipy

In addition I still get the original error message.

Please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all possible things suggested in various forums this is what worked for me:

1. Download numpy-1.11.2+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl and scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl files from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy to C:\Python27\Scripts directory.
2. Run the following commands from the DOS command window in windows

   pip install numpy-1.11.2+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

   pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

They were both successfully installed.

3. Finally

   pip install ggplot