# Python: How to install neuralpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network

if I try to install neuralpy with `sudo pip install neuralpy`, I have this kind of error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-ziqu6pe6/neuralpy/

Answer (score 0):

Mostly from [pip install numpy (python 2.7) fails with errorcode 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142839/pip-install-numpy-python-2-7-fails-with-errorcode-1)

Download the wheel (.whl file) file from here and install with pip:
Link: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

```
pip install wheel to install support for wheel files.
```

Now go to the folder where the file is and press shift + right click and click on open command prompt here

Then type

```
pip install [File that you download]
```

to install the wheel.